# My Node package requires two packages that both have the same dependencies. That ok?

Tags: node.js, package, npm

My node package currently requires `express` and `locomotive`. Both `express` and  `locomotive` require the `commander` package.

When each package (`express` and `locomotive`) requires commander, this will resolve to two different files. Based on [Node's documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats), the `commander` package will get executed twice and there will be two master copies of the `commander` package, one for each file, within my app.

Now, based on my understanding of [`require.resolve()`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together), require() will search up the directory tree all the way up to the machine's root directory (or as far up as the user is allowed) and look in every single directory along the way for `./node_modules/commander`.

Should I then consolidate the `commander` package (and all other duplicate packages) into the `node_modules` folder at the root of my app?

EDIT 12:58 p.m.: I also noticed that the duplicate packages may not be of the same version. `express` has `commander 0.6.1` while `locomotive` has `commander 1.0.4`. Another dependency `express` and `locomotive` share is `mkdirp` at `0.3.3` and `0.3.4`, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each package installs its own dependencies in their respective `node_modules` folder on installation.

For instance, `express` would have it's own `node_modules` folder with it's specific version of `commander` in it, and the other module would have it's own.

To confirm;

```
mkdir someNewProject && cd someNewProject
npm install express locomotive
```

Then see the directory structure of those installed modules with something like this;

```
ls node_modules/express
ls node_modules/locomotive
```

You should notice they each have their own `node_modules` folders with their dependencies.  Therefore, I would not advise trying to make a common commander package.

Comment: Yeah. This is how `npm` works and simple `npm install -d` installs all dependencies at once :)